# Ignore case in prettyfaces pattern

Tags: prettyfaces

if you defined a url mapping as follows:

```
@URLMapping(id = "myPage", pattern = "/myPage", viewId = "/faces/pages/myPage.xhtml")
```

if you tried to enter the url as:

```
http:localhost:8080/myPage
```

this will work fine, but if you changed the case to:

```
http:localhost:8080/mypage
```

or `http:localhost:8080/MYPAGE`

it won't work, it won't find the page, so is there's a way to ignore the case in the pattern, or such thing is not supported in PrettyFaces yet, if not supported, then please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this is currently not directly supported with PrettyFaces. But you could achieve something like this with a simple workaround:

Change your mapping to a completely lowercase URL:

```
@URLMapping(id = "myPage", pattern = "/mypage", viewId = "/faces/pages/myPage.xhtml")
```

And then add a rewrite rule that performs the lowercase transformation:

```
<rewrite match="(?i)/mypage" toCase="lowercase" redirect="chain" />
```

I think this should work fine. You could also try to build a more general pattern so that you don't have to repeat the rewrite rule for every mapping.